# Incorrect message while uploading a too large image from the Internet

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader

According to the message in the upload image dialog, image size must be max of 2Mb. But if I try to upload image from the Internet of larger size, the result message will be:

> [image: not supported]

This is somewhat discouraging.

Message for uploading large image from disk is OK:

> [image: too large]

Comment: The whole industry is riddled with confusing and/or incorrect error messages and always has been.  ENIAC had wrong error messages.  Colossus had wrong error messages.  The abacus has wrong error messages.  It just is, and there's never time/money to fix them.

Comment: @MartinJames I do not insist on fixing. Just want you to know about the bug.

Comment: Are you also trying to upload a format not supported that is large, maybe that error is thrown before the size one is

Comment: @depperm I tried to download that picture and upload as local file. In this case I got `too large` error. You could try for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. You should see the correct error message after our next build today.

We had been conflating [all 400-status errors from the Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/errorhandling#400). We now separately distinguish file format and file size errors.